# Update (and grow) dialog when new components are added

Tags: java, swing, layout

I've got JDialog window where the user can add components manually with a "+" knob.

I would like my window to be resized automatically after each addition.

`pack()` works before the dialog is set visible. But it is already visible, it doesn't change de windows dimension.

Is there a alternate/complementary way to `pack()` ?

Kind regards,

Comment: What are you going to do when a user grows your JDialog bigger than the screen?  Perhaps you should put your components inside a JScrollPane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the JScrollPane is the "problem" for the pack, I let the pack() compute everything. If the panel inside de JScrollPane is bigger than the scrollpane and still at reasonable dimension, I force the JDialog to a bigger size:

```
pack();

Dimension dimPanels = panObjects.getSize();
Dimension dimWindow = this.getSize();
Dimension dimScroll = jScrollPane1.getSize();

int targetHeight = dimPanels.height - dimScroll.height + dimWindow.height;

if ((dimPanels.height > dimScroll.height) && (targetHeight < MAX_WINDOW_HEIGHT)) {
    this.setSize(dimWindow.width, targetHeight);
    validate();
}
else if (targetHeight > MAX_WINDOW_HEIGHT) {
    this.setSize(dimWindow.width, MAX_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    validate();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a alternate/complementary way to pack() ?

No, use `pack()` as this is the only call that will not only re-lay out the components but will resize the containing top-level window (here a JDialog).

> But it is already visible, it doesn't change de windows dimension.

It doesn't matter if the window is already visible. If `pack()` is called **on the visualized top-level Window** ( a big if), then it **will** change the window's dimensions, if your GUI is using layout managers properly. If yours are not being changed, then perhaps you're not calling this method on the correct reference or are not using layouts in a good way, and in this situation, you will want to show us pertinent code.

Your question begs another question -- why not use `pack()`? If it's because the changes are being done to a JPanel that is held by the JDialog, then you can always get the dialog or whatever top-level window holds the JPanel (or any component) using `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(Component c)`.

Comment: My problem is the JScrollPane I put around the panel that holds the "add-able" subpanels (I anticipated Gilbert Le Blanc remark). Without the JScrollPane, the `pack()` works fine, but I've the risk that the window become bigger than the screen.  With the JScrollPane, I cover that risks but the reisze is not automatic. Is there a way to have something intermediary ? The windows keeps growing automatically until a certain size (to be determined) and beyond that size the JScrollPane shows up ?

Comment: @lvr123 I think that you'll want to create and post a minimal code example, a very small compilable and runnable example that shows us exactly your problem.